# Plotly ignores autorange in animation

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm currently trying to create an animation in Plotly using Numpy Arrays. The creation of the individual plots works nicely, however when I try to add the individual plots as frames for the animation, the ranging (both autorange and the given limits) are completely ignored. Here's the code:

```
def animationTest(fields):
    fig = go.Figure(
        data=[
            go.Scatter3d()
        ],
        layout=go.Layout(
            xaxis=dict(
                range=[-1.,1.],
                autorange=False
            ),
            yaxis=dict(
                range=[-1.,1.],
                autorange=False
            ),
            updatemenus=[
                dict(
                    type='buttons',
                    buttons=[
                        dict(
                            label='Play',
                            method='animate',
                            args=[None]
                        )
                    ]
                )
            ]
        ),
        frames=[
            go.Frame(
                data=[
                    go.Scatter3d(
                        x=it.x,
                        y=it.y,
                        z=it.z,
                        line=dict(color='red',width=2)
                    )
                ],
                layout=go.Layout(
                    xaxis=dict(
                        range=[-1.,1.],
                        autorange=False
                    ),
                    yaxis=dict(
                        range=[-1.,1.],
                        autorange=False
                    )                
                )
            )
        for it in its]
    )
    fig.show()
```

In this case, `its` is a list of objects where each object `it` has a numpy array of 501 numeric values for each attribute `x,y,z`, respectively.

Can anyone figure out why the autorange given in the go.Layout() object is ignored? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have since figured out the problem - the above given code:

```
go.Layout(
    xaxis=dict(range=[-1.,1.])
)
```

is the syntax for 2D plots. To adjust the axis limits for 3D plots, use:

```
go.layout(
    scene=dict(
        xaxis=dict(range=[-1,1])
    )
)
```

instead, and it should work.